# SSH not working correctly via PHP exec

Tags: php, ssh

Hey I'm attempting to utilise the PHP SSH2 functions of which I've used a class from over a GitHub: [Here](https://github.com/members/ssh) but doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I'm trying to `cd` into a directory and then list files, but seems to ignore the `cd` and when I use the `ls` command it just displays the root dir.

Here's when I perform a normal `ls` on my root directory:

```
drwx------  6 root root 4096 Aug 12 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Aug 11 08:28 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 2963 Aug 12 18:33 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Oct 22  2015 .bashrc
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Aug 11 21:05 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 12 18:21 .local
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12 18:22 .nano
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Aug 11 21:07 myOtherDirectory
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
-rw-------  1 root root 1024 Aug 12 18:27 .rnd
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  252 Aug 12 18:28 .wget-hsts
```

And here's then I try to access the `myOtherDirectory` using SSH via PHP

```
$ssh = new ssh("ip", "root", "pass");
$ssh("cd myOtherDirectory");
$result = $ssh("ls -la");
print_r($result);
```

Comment: What is `myOtherDirectory`?  When you login as root you'll be in the `/root` dir so you would need to give the absolute path such as `/myOtherDirectory` or `/path/to/myOtherDirectory`

Comment: `echo $ssh("cd myOtherDirectory");` to see if it returns an error.

Comment: @AbraCadaver it returns an empty response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSH protocol permits you to make one SSH connection (called a *session*) to a remote host and then run multiple channels through the single connection. A single channel can represent an interactive session, a single SFTP transfer, and so on. Each channel is independent of the others.

```
$ssh = new ssh("ip", "root", "pass");
$ssh("cd myOtherDirectory");
$result = $ssh("ls -la");
```

What you're doing here is creating a single SSH session to the remote host, then creating two channels. The first channel runs `cd` and then exits. The second channel runs `ls` and then exits. The two channels are independent of each other, so the `cd` invocation has no effect on the working directory of the `ls` invocation.

You want to run both commands in a single session. Assuming the remote system is using `bash` or a similar shell to run commands, this ought to work:

```
$ssh = new ssh("ip", "root", "pass");
$result = $ssh("cd myOtherDirectory && ls -la");
```

Alternately, you could specify the correct remote directory in the `ls` command:

```
$ssh = new ssh("ip", "root", "pass");
$result = $ssh("ls -la myOtherDirectory");
```

Comment: You're a genius, you saved the day!